# CakePHP : display data from multiple models

Tags: cakephp, multiple-tables, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

I am working on a service request application on CakePHP 2.7.8. 
I have to display a list of clients offering requested service in user's area.

For this I have a `service_requests` table in the database to keep track of requests made by users.

```
CREATE TABLE `service_requests` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_area_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Note here `service_id` and `service_area_id` which are foreign keys of two different models `services` and `service_areas` respectively.

**services.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and **service_areas.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `service_areas` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `postal_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `postal_id_idx` (`postal_id`)
)
```

I have another table to maintain list of services provided by clients (service providers).

```
CREATE TABLE `client_services` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL COMMENT '      ',
  `client_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charge` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id_idx` (`client_id`),
  KEY `service_id_idx` (`service_id`)
)
```

and another table to maintain list of service areas covered under service providers.

```
CREATE TABLE `client_service_areas` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_area_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id_idx` (`client_id`),
  KEY `service_area_id_idx` (`service_area_id`)
)
```

---

**serviceReqest model : serviceRequest.php**

```
class ServiceRequest extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'status';

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Customer' => array(
            'className' => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'CustomerAddress' => array(
            'className' => 'CustomerAddress',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Service' => array(
            'className' => 'Service',
            'foreignKey' => 'service_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ServiceArea' => array(
            'className' => 'ServiceArea',
            'foreignKey' => 'service_area_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

On requesting `view` action by accessing:

```
http://localhost/service_requests/view/<service_request_id>
```

it displays result from service_requests

[image: service request view action]

Now what I want to do is to display a list below this view containing client's name who provides requested service in the requested service area *(there can be many service providers offering same service in same service area).*

This means showing a list of clients who provide services for `Carpenter` in `Ghaziabad`

The client's name and other details are fetched from `clients` table.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Comment: I'm new to CakePHP and this is my first project after following blog tutorial so, seeking for ideas where to start from.

Comment: so maybe stackoverflow is not the right place to ask for help, take a look at the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about what is considered off-topic. Also: if it's your first cake project why not starting with cakephp 3 instead of cakephp 2?

Comment: I am working on Netbeans IDE and there is no official supported plugin for CakePHP 3.0

Comment: https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp3-netbeans

Comment: I will update this question after some work.

Comment: Is `customers` and `clients` the same thing? I see you have both `customer_id` and `client_id`.

Comment: no both are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your data model:

[image]

You can retrieve the information you need by joining `clients` with `client_services` and `client_service_areas`, filtering by `service_id` and `service_area_id`, and grouping by `clients.id`.

The following should work:

```
public function view($id){

    // retrieve ServiceRequest data 
    $serviceRequest = $this->ServiceRequest->findById($id);

    // retrieve Client data        
    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'client_services',
            'alias' => 'ClientService',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Client.id = ClientService.client_id',
            )
        ),
        array('table' => 'client_service_areas',
            'alias' => 'ClientServiceArea',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Client.id = ClientServiceArea.client_id',
            )
        ),

    );

    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'ClientService.service_id'=>$serviceRequest['ServiceRequest']['service_id'],
        'ClientServiceArea.service_area_id'=>$serviceRequest['ServiceRequest']['service_area_id']
    );

    $options['group'] = array('Client.id');

    $Client = ClassRegistry::init('Client');
    $clients = $Client->find('all', $options);
    $this->set(compact('serviceRequest','clients'));
}
```

<sub>Note: The above code  is untested and lacks error handling</sub>

Comment: `+50` bounty has been awarded to you @inigo-flores. You deserve it

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to  this code.
`$query = $articles->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')])
    ->contain(['Comments', 'Authors'])
    ->limit(10);`

you can study this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)